# What online REST API workbenches are available?

Tags: api, rest

When creating a site/script to be on the client end of a RESTful API, what tools are available to create a "workbench" to explore the API, examining headers and responses while working through the design? Preferably one(s) that allow you to enter a custom endpoint, and create sample requests to see the responses. I recall seeing one nice workbench before, but its name has escaped me.

Answer (score 1):

Re-found the one I remembered: The [Apigee Console](https://apigee.com/console/others) is a great interface for playing around with an existing API or building your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `wadl` file of the ReST Services, you can load it in SOAP UI and use it.

**Edited**
Another much simpler tool [Rest Client](http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/)

Comment: Are you referring to http://www.soapui.org/About-SoapUI/what-is-soapui.html or some other product? Also, SOAP is not really a RESTful service, and not what I was looking for.

Comment: @MidnightLightning the tool is SoapUI. It has very good support for ReST Services. It started as a SOAP testing tool but has evloved far from that. And if you have the `wadl` for your rest services you can very well explore the APIs. Try out using this wadl http://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/#x3-40001.3

Answer (score 0):

Mashery's [I/O Docs](http://www.mashery.com/product/io-docs) is an [open source](https://github.com/mashery/iodocs) workbench that you can deploy yourself on a Node.js server with Redis for storage.